# Magento2: How to remove the newsletter block?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, blocks, static-block

I have newsletter signup block on my front page that I want to remove. However I can't seem to find it anywhere.  With development mode I can see that it is being rendered from `app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/Spiceli/Magento_Newsletter/templates/subscribe.phtml`
and that it is `Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe` from this two information is there a way to can remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can remove this block completely via layout with `remove="true"`:

*app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/Spiceli/Magento_Newsletter/layout/default.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: thank you that works; just so I know where was this define in the first place?

Comment: Take a look this layout: `vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`